# Troubleshooting ECS task failing container health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, docker, amazon-ecs

We are trying to transition our AWS EC2 instance to AWS ECS service running under Elastic Load Balancer. This EC2 instance is responsible for receiving a lot of network connections and saving received data to S3 bucket and sql. Problem is no matter how many tasks we scale up to or how big they are, they still fail container health check once it is used in production. Container health check we are using is this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Instead of pinging apache we can only check the service's status for incoming due to the high load apache deals with
cgi-fcgi -bind -connect localhost:9001 \
    && service apache2 status \
    && service cron status \
    && service ssh status \
    && service awslogs status \
    && service td-agent status \
    || exit 1
```

Currently I have 1 ECS task with max capacity of 2. Each task has 4 vCPU units and 16GB of RAM. Our original EC2 instance is of m5.2xlarge type and has 32GB of RAM and 8vCPU units. EC2 instance does not ever reach 100% CPU and Memory, so ECS tasks should be big enough to handle this network load.

Once we start sending requests to ECS task, it response from server becomes slower(requests taking 45 seconds) and then health check script eventually fails and ECS kills the task.

I have also tried using [apache2buddy](https://github.com/richardforth/apache2buddy) script to tune performance of apache2 web server, but it did not help as the script did not report any issues. Also tailing syslog and apache2 error log is not helpful as there are no obvious errors logged. So I am trying to find more ways to troubleshoot this and find why EC2 instance has no problems with all these network requests but docker container running on ECS does.

Comment: If you are running LB then why you need task level health check? LB health check should be enough with an appropriate delay
also why you are running awslogs when ECS provide aws llog driver?

Comment: @Adiii Thing is, even if we disable container health checks, then LB health checks fail as well.

Comment: On which port LB health check is configured? what is the timeout?

Comment: @Adiii Timeout is maximum 120 seconds and port is default HTTP port. Im sure port is correct because it does work in the beginning and fails once response time gets slow enough.

Comment: okay, you can explore custom health check, a lightweight js script that return success to first LB call and do health check in the background.

Comment: @Adiii Are you sure such thing exists? I cant find anything like this on google. These ELB health checks will ping health check endpoint continuously until server response is too slow and it fails.